# Using hogan.js with express.js + vhosts

Tags: templates, node.js, express, hogan.js

What is the correct way to use hogan.js with express.js?

I've tried the following:

```
var hogan = require('hogan.js')
...
app.set('view engine', 'hogan');
```

followed by

```
app.register('.hogan', hogan);
```

But I end up with the following error:

```
500 Error: Cannot find module 'hogan'
```

TJ put out a library called consolidate.js ( https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js ) but I'm having trouble getting it to work with Express 2.5.8.  After spending the day trying to figure this out I also came across a library called hulk-hogan.js ( https://github.com/quangv/hulk-hogan ) and another called hogan-express ( http://allampersandall.blogspot.com/2011/12/hoganjs-expressjs-nodejs.html ).  But, do I really need all that?

If the solution can  not be as simple as setting the templating engine with app.set() and app.register(), it would be great if someone could help me understand why.  I'm using Hogan on the client and it's working great, it would just be so much better if I could also use it on the server.

UPDATE: Turns out there are two issues here.

1. While this is not causing the `500 error`, Express does not work with Hogan out of the box (see: Linus G Thiel's answer below)
2. What seems to be causing the `500 error` is that I'm using a virtual host and when I call res.render(), my res.render() call is actually calling the res.render() of a different virtual host on my same server.

Adding the full Express error dump.  It looks like my app ('dataviz') is trying to use the render call from a different app ('datavizblocks')?  Again, the two apps are virtual hosts on the same server.

```
dataviz 8000
Error: Cannot find module 'hogan.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at View.templateEngine (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view/view.js:134:38)
    at Function.compile (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:68:17)
    at ServerResponse._render (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:417:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:318:17)
    at /localhost/dataviz/routes/section.js:325:7
    at callbacks (/localhost/dataviz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
dataviz 8000
Error: Cannot find module 'hogan.js'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at View.templateEngine (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view/view.js:134:38)
    at Function.compile (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:68:17)
    at ServerResponse._render (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:417:18)
    at ServerResponse.render (/localhost/datavizblocks/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:318:17)
    at /localhost/dataviz/routes/section.js:325:7
    at callbacks (/localhost/dataviz/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:272:11)
```

The `500 error` goes away when I comment out the `datavizblock` vhost, or when I switch the order of the vhost declarations around to have the `dataviz` vhost declared after `datavizblocks` vhost (of course, this then causes problems for the `datavizblocks` vhost)

Apologies ahead of time for the confusing question, but I was really confused when I came across this issue and never expected that switching to `Hogan` would have conflicts with  virtual hosting.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that Express requires an interface from template engines, where the template engine is expected to have a `compile` method, and that `compile` method is expected to return a function which can be called with the template data.

Hogan has a `compile` method, but it returns a template object which has a `render` method. You need to expose that `render` method to Express, and this seems to be what the `hogan-express` module does. It shouldn't have to be that involved though, I *think* this will work (I have only tested it slightly, might be some gotchas?):

```
var express = require('express'),
    hogan = require('hogan.js'),
    app = express.createServer();

app.set('view engine', 'hogan');
app.register('hogan', {
    compile: function() {
        var t = hogan.compile.apply(hogan, arguments);
        return function() {
            return t.render.apply(t, arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

Basically, we are just creating our own object that has a `compile` method that maps to Hogan's `render` method.

This expects your templates to be named e.g. `index.hogan`.

Comment: Aaah!!  Of course!  Great answer...funny thing is this is very similar to what I had to do to get Hogan working with Backbone (slaps forehead)...I'll verify later on...

Comment: Looks like something else is wrong.  I added this code but I'm still getting the same `Error: Cannot find module 'hogan.js"` when I try to load the page

Comment: Are you sure you installed `hogan.js`? There is also a module `hogan` in the npm registry. I'm not sure which you want, but `hogan.js` looks a bit more active.

Comment: yeah...the require('hogan.js') call in app.js seems to work fine, the error shows up only when it attempts to render.  I also verified the /hogan.js/package.json does show the name to be "hogan.js".  I'm realizing I should have added the Express error dump...adding it to the post now...

Comment: fixed now...@Linus, I updated your answer with the fix.  Still, however, anyone seeing this should note that it won't address issues with using {layout: true}, but that's a separate issue...

Answer (score 2):

As Linus said, you need an adapter to use Hogan with Express. consolidate works fine as long as you don't need support for partials or layouts (they are working on it but I don't know when it will be ready).

I was in the same spot you're in a few months ago and found hulk-hogan's and express-hogan's documentations to be quite confusing so I coded my own wrapper that has support for partials, layouts, template caching and can be plugged in Express in one line of code. You can check it out here: [h4e - templating with hogan for express](https://github.com/tldrio/h4e)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully.

Comment: Further, your answer here does not actually address the *specific* question being asked. In such a case, advertising your own code is generally not accepted to be appropriate as an answer.

Comment: Sorry about that. I posted it here because I believe it does answer the question. You have two ways to connect hoganjs to expressjs: manually or with a wrapper. manually is a pain (not hard but still), and the two wrappers I found before coding this (hulk-hogan and express-hogan) were poorly document and hard to grasp. I could have included this in my answer, for sure.